# Content of tab-group disappears before header when using route-animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations, angular-material-tab

I have added a FadeIn/FadeOut animation as a route animation for my application. When I added a tab group as the page content, I noticed the following. When I enter the page, everything works as it should. The tab group fades in slowly. When I leave the page, the content of the tab group disappears immediately, while the header slowly fades out as normal. When I observe this with the browser's dev tools, I see that the content disappears immediately in the DOM.

I have created a Stackblitz Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3f9bcw?file=src/app/page-one/page-one.component.html):
Unfortunately, I have not found any explanation or solution. What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?